# How to destroy barriers for easier snapshot?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

One way to use snapshot snipper is to ensure that there is a line of sight between the sniper and the enemies.

Tons of barriers are often in a way. Enemies are often hidden in building. Blaster launchers can only be used a number of times.

Are there any reliable ways to keep destroying all those pesky covers.

Comment: Do you really mean Snapshot? That let's you move and shoot in the same turn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### KABOOM

Yes, explosives are limited per battle but they are absolutely wonderful for wrecking cover. Other than rocket launchers, the whole squad can carry grenades. The grenade doesn't have the same blast radius as rockets, but it will destroy cover (and building walls) just the same.

#### Falcon PUNCH!

MECs upgraded with the "kinetic strike module" are able to punch anything in the 4 squares directly next to them (no diagonals). Punching does not consume ammo or have a limited number of times per battle. It will destroy pretty much any destructible cover. However this does have a few drawbacks. You will be getting your MECs very close to enemies in order to destroy their cover and by that point it might be a better idea to punch the aliens instead. For even more fun, punch an enemy that is in front of cover and the enemy will fly back and break the cover they land on! (Yelling "falcon PUNCH!" at the screen as you do this is highly recommended but not required.)

#### PEW PEW

Conventional (bullet) weapons won't do much about cover, but the more powerful laser and plasma weapons have a chance to destroy cover if you miss your shot at an alien using it. Laser weapons will destroy cover once in a while. Plasma weapons will rip through cover almost every time. Heavies using the suppression ability will also destroy the cover of whatever they are suppressing (at the cost of burning through ammo very quickly). The best part about letting the lasers and plasma do the work is that it turns all of your shots against cover into a win-win; either you hit the alien or burn the cover away so it's easier to hit them next time.

#### Y U Do Dis

Destroying cover to wreck a bunch of aliens with In The Zone is all well and good, but it is also highly situational, meaning it doesn't always work out. Sometimes the aliens don't feel like hanging out in the open in a cluster right next to your snapshot sniper. If it's not coming together, you may be better off trying other tactics rather than spending turns nuking all the cover.

Personally, I've had much more success with a squadsight sniper dealing consistent damage from high ground across the map, but that's just my playstyle.

Comment: would be nice if you can destroy the roof. You can't aim your plasma to destroy the roof. That's the problem.

Comment: @JimThio I thought you were talking about vertical cover, like boxes and containers. I don't know of anything that will destroy horizontal cover, like a roof or floor of a building.